# Flatten Lists in JSON file with R

Tags: r, jsonlite

I have a JSON file from a data provider in the following format (at the end of post).

I can use `jsonlite` to read the JSON into R but the last to columns are lists and I can't figure out how to unpack the lists. The second to last column is null and the last column is a list with 15 entries.

`example <- fromJSON('example.json')`

`summary(example)`

```
ScoreId          Season       SeasonType      Week        Day              DateTime        
 Min.   :16878   Min.   :2018   Min.   :1    Min.   :16   Length:16          Length:16         
 1st Qu.:16882   1st Qu.:2018   1st Qu.:1    1st Qu.:16   Class :character   Class :character  
 Median :16886   Median :2018   Median :1    Median :16   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :16886   Mean   :2018   Mean   :1    Mean   :16                                        
 3rd Qu.:16889   3rd Qu.:2018   3rd Qu.:1    3rd Qu.:16                                        
 Max.   :16893   Max.   :2018   Max.   :1    Max.   :16                                        

... 

PregameOdds.Length  PregameOdds.Class  PregameOdds.Mode
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 0       -none-  list                                   
 LiveOdds.Length  LiveOdds.Class  LiveOdds.Mode
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list                  
 15          data.frame  list
```

I'm not wedded to `jsonlite` though it seems to be the preferred library.

File:

```
[{
  "ScoreId": 16881,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-22T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-22T16:30:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 35,
  "HomeTeamId": 34,
  "AwayTeamName": "WAS",
  "HomeTeamName": "TEN",
  "GlobalGameId": 16881,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 35,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 34,
  "HomeTeamScore": 28,
  "AwayTeamScore": 18,
  "TotalScore": 46,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 95703,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16881,
    "Created": "2018-12-22T19:04:18",
    "Updated": "2018-12-22T19:24:55",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": 0.0,
    "AwayPointSpread": 0.0,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": -281,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": 238,
    "OverUnder": null,
    "OverPayout": null,
    "UnderPayout": null
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16889,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-22T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-22T20:20:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 3,
  "HomeTeamId": 29,
  "AwayTeamName": "BAL",
  "HomeTeamName": "LAC",
  "GlobalGameId": 16889,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 3,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 29,
  "HomeTeamScore": 11,
  "AwayTeamScore": 24,
  "TotalScore": 36,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 95933,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16889,
    "Created": "2018-12-22T23:12:29",
    "Updated": "2018-12-22T23:24:59",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": 13.0,
    "AwayPointSpread": -13.0,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": 132,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -172,
    "OverUnder": 36.6,
    "OverPayout": 117,
    "UnderPayout": -147
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16878,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T13:00:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 7,
  "HomeTeamId": 8,
  "AwayTeamName": "CIN",
  "HomeTeamName": "CLE",
  "GlobalGameId": 16878,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 7,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 8,
  "HomeTeamScore": 29,
  "AwayTeamScore": 20,
  "TotalScore": 49,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 98674,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16878,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T14:22:38",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T15:54:51",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": -20.8,
    "AwayPointSpread": 20.8,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": -153,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": 119,
    "OverUnder": 40.0,
    "OverPayout": -148,
    "UnderPayout": 116
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16879,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T13:00:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 33,
  "HomeTeamId": 9,
  "AwayTeamName": "TB",
  "HomeTeamName": "DAL",
  "GlobalGameId": 16879,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 33,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 9,
  "HomeTeamScore": 30,
  "AwayTeamScore": 22,
  "TotalScore": 52,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 99556,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16879,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T15:49:51",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T16:09:54",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": -15.2,
    "AwayPointSpread": 15.2,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": -362,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": 258,
    "OverUnder": 45.6,
    "OverPayout": 118,
    "UnderPayout": -148
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16880,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T13:00:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 20,
  "HomeTeamId": 11,
  "AwayTeamName": "MIN",
  "HomeTeamName": "DET",
  "GlobalGameId": 16880,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 20,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 11,
  "HomeTeamScore": 10,
  "AwayTeamScore": 30,
  "TotalScore": 40,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 99448,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16880,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T15:36:07",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T16:19:49",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": 16.3,
    "AwayPointSpread": -16.3,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": 200,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -231,
    "OverUnder": null,
    "OverPayout": null,
    "UnderPayout": null
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16882,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T13:00:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 23,
  "HomeTeamId": 14,
  "AwayTeamName": "NYG",
  "HomeTeamName": "IND",
  "GlobalGameId": 16882,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 23,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 14,
  "HomeTeamScore": 31,
  "AwayTeamScore": 30,
  "TotalScore": 61,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 99596,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16882,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T15:58:43",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T16:09:54",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": 0.0,
    "AwayPointSpread": 0.0,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": -273,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": 233,
    "OverUnder": null,
    "OverPayout": null,
    "UnderPayout": null
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16883,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T13:00:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 15,
  "HomeTeamId": 19,
  "AwayTeamName": "JAX",
  "HomeTeamName": "MIA",
  "GlobalGameId": 16883,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 15,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 19,
  "HomeTeamScore": 7,
  "AwayTeamScore": 19,
  "TotalScore": 27,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 99402,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16883,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T15:28:43",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T15:59:57",
    "HomeMoneyLine": 169,
    "AwayMoneyLine": -236,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": 2.8,
    "AwayPointSpread": -2.8,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": 139,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -178,
    "OverUnder": 28.7,
    "OverPayout": 130,
    "UnderPayout": -165
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16884,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T13:00:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 4,
  "HomeTeamId": 21,
  "AwayTeamName": "BUF",
  "HomeTeamName": "NE",
  "GlobalGameId": 16884,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 4,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 21,
  "HomeTeamScore": 27,
  "AwayTeamScore": 13,
  "TotalScore": 40,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 98928,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16884,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T14:50:56",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T16:09:54",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": -19.7,
    "AwayPointSpread": 19.7,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": 160,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -206,
    "OverUnder": 42.3,
    "OverPayout": -120,
    "UnderPayout": -135
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16885,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T13:00:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 12,
  "HomeTeamId": 24,
  "AwayTeamName": "GB",
  "HomeTeamName": "NYJ",
  "GlobalGameId": 16885,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 12,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 24,
  "HomeTeamScore": 42,
  "AwayTeamScore": 49,
  "TotalScore": 92,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 99828,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16885,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T16:37:09",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T16:59:50",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": 0.0,
    "AwayPointSpread": 0.0,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": 145,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -189,
    "OverUnder": null,
    "OverPayout": null,
    "UnderPayout": null
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16886,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T13:00:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 13,
  "HomeTeamId": 26,
  "AwayTeamName": "HOU",
  "HomeTeamName": "PHI",
  "GlobalGameId": 16886,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 13,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 26,
  "HomeTeamScore": 36,
  "AwayTeamScore": 33,
  "TotalScore": 69,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 99727,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16886,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T16:19:15",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T16:24:59",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": 0.0,
    "AwayPointSpread": 0.0,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": -786,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": 579,
    "OverUnder": null,
    "OverPayout": null,
    "UnderPayout": null
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16887,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T13:00:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 2,
  "HomeTeamId": 5,
  "AwayTeamName": "ATL",
  "HomeTeamName": "CAR",
  "GlobalGameId": 16887,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 2,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 5,
  "HomeTeamScore": 11,
  "AwayTeamScore": 27,
  "TotalScore": 38,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 98708,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16887,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T14:24:55",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T16:14:49",
    "HomeMoneyLine": 113,
    "AwayMoneyLine": -158,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": 2.8,
    "AwayPointSpread": -2.8,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": -112,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -142,
    "OverUnder": 49.0,
    "OverPayout": -116,
    "UnderPayout": -137
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16888,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T16:05:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 32,
  "HomeTeamId": 1,
  "AwayTeamName": "LAR",
  "HomeTeamName": "ARI",
  "GlobalGameId": 16888,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 32,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 1,
  "HomeTeamScore": 10,
  "AwayTeamScore": 34,
  "TotalScore": 45,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 100259,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16888,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T18:37:44",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T19:09:59",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": 25.4,
    "AwayPointSpread": -25.4,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": -274,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": 233,
    "OverUnder": null,
    "OverPayout": null,
    "UnderPayout": null
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16890,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T16:05:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 6,
  "HomeTeamId": 31,
  "AwayTeamName": "CHI",
  "HomeTeamName": "SF",
  "GlobalGameId": 16890,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 6,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 31,
  "HomeTeamScore": 10,
  "AwayTeamScore": 15,
  "TotalScore": 25,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 100317,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16890,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T19:00:17",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T19:19:59",
    "HomeMoneyLine": 1350,
    "AwayMoneyLine": -2819,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": null,
    "AwayPointSpread": null,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": null,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": null,
    "OverUnder": null,
    "OverPayout": null,
    "UnderPayout": null
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16891,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T16:25:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 28,
  "HomeTeamId": 22,
  "AwayTeamName": "PIT",
  "HomeTeamName": "NO",
  "GlobalGameId": 16891,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 28,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 22,
  "HomeTeamScore": 34,
  "AwayTeamScore": 31,
  "TotalScore": 66,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 100417,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16891,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T19:43:32",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T19:59:58",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": 0.0,
    "AwayPointSpread": 0.0,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": -244,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": 211,
    "OverUnder": null,
    "OverPayout": null,
    "UnderPayout": null
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16892,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-23T20:20:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 16,
  "HomeTeamId": 30,
  "AwayTeamName": "KC",
  "HomeTeamName": "SEA",
  "GlobalGameId": 16892,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 16,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 30,
  "HomeTeamScore": 42,
  "AwayTeamScore": 34,
  "TotalScore": 77,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 100950,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16892,
    "Created": "2018-12-23T23:41:01",
    "Updated": "2018-12-23T23:54:58",
    "HomeMoneyLine": -2257,
    "AwayMoneyLine": 1193,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": -1.7,
    "AwayPointSpread": 1.7,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": -1688,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": 741,
    "OverUnder": null,
    "OverPayout": null,
    "UnderPayout": null
  }]
}, {
  "ScoreId": 16893,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Week": 16,
  "Day": "2018-12-24T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-12-24T20:15:00",
  "AwayTeamId": 10,
  "HomeTeamId": 25,
  "AwayTeamName": "DEN",
  "HomeTeamName": "OAK",
  "GlobalGameId": 16893,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 10,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 25,
  "HomeTeamScore": 30,
  "AwayTeamScore": 15,
  "TotalScore": 46,
  "PregameOdds": [],
  "LiveOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 101804,
    "Sportsbook": null,
    "ScoreId": 16893,
    "Created": "2018-12-24T22:58:47",
    "Updated": "2018-12-24T23:24:51",
    "HomeMoneyLine": null,
    "AwayMoneyLine": null,
    "DrawMoneyLine": null,
    "HomePointSpread": -10.7,
    "AwayPointSpread": 10.7,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": -110,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -127,
    "OverUnder": null,
    "OverPayout": null,
    "UnderPayout": null
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
out <- fromJSON("example.json") %>% 
              select(-PregameOdds) %>% # remove the column with empty list
                   unnest(LiveOdds)
```

-structure

```
str(out)
#'data.frame':  16 obs. of  31 variables:
# $ ScoreId              : int  16881 16889 16878 16879 16880 16882 16883 16884 16885 16886 ...
# $ Season               : int  2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 ...
# $ SeasonType           : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ Week                 : int  16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
# $ Day                  : chr  "2018-12-22T00:00:00" "2018-12-22T00:00:00" "2018-12-23T00:00:00" "2018-12-23T00:00:00" ...
# $ DateTime             : chr  "2018-12-22T16:30:00" "2018-12-22T20:20:00" "2018-12-23T13:00:00" "2018-12-23T13:00:00" ...
# $ AwayTeamId           : int  35 3 7 33 20 23 15 4 12 13 ...
# $ HomeTeamId           : int  34 29 8 9 11 14 19 21 24 26 ...
# $ AwayTeamName         : chr  "WAS" "BAL" "CIN" "TB" ...
# $ HomeTeamName         : chr  "TEN" "LAC" "CLE" "DAL" ...
# $ GlobalGameId         : int  16881 16889 16878 16879 16880 16882 16883 16884 16885 16886 ...
# $ GlobalAwayTeamId     : int  35 3 7 33 20 23 15 4 12 13 ...
# $ GlobalHomeTeamId     : int  34 29 8 9 11 14 19 21 24 26 ...
# $ HomeTeamScore        : int  28 11 29 30 10 31 7 27 42 36 ...
# $ AwayTeamScore        : int  18 24 20 22 30 30 19 13 49 33 ...
# $ TotalScore           : int  46 36 49 52 40 61 27 40 92 69 ...
# $ GameOddId            : int  95703 95933 98674 99556 99448 99596 99402 98928 99828 99727 ...
# $ Sportsbook           : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
# $ ScoreId1             : int  16881 16889 16878 16879 16880 16882 16883 16884 16885 16886 ...
# $ Created              : chr  "2018-12-22T19:04:18" "2018-12-22T23:12:29" "2018-12-23T14:22:38" "2018-12-23T15:49:51" ...
# $ Updated              : chr  "2018-12-22T19:24:55" "2018-12-22T23:24:59" "2018-12-23T15:54:51" "2018-12-23T16:09:54" ...
# $ HomeMoneyLine        : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA 169 NA NA NA ...
# $ AwayMoneyLine        : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA -236 NA NA NA ...
# $ DrawMoneyLine        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
# $ HomePointSpread      : num  0 13 -20.8 -15.2 16.3 0 2.8 -19.7 0 0 ...
# $ AwayPointSpread      : num  0 -13 20.8 15.2 -16.3 0 -2.8 19.7 0 0 ...
# $ HomePointSpreadPayout: int  -281 132 -153 -362 200 -273 139 160 145 -786 ...
# $ AwayPointSpreadPayout: int  238 -172 119 258 -231 233 -178 -206 -189 579 ...
# $ OverUnder            : num  NA 36.6 40 45.6 NA NA 28.7 42.3 NA NA ...
# $ OverPayout           : int  NA 117 -148 118 NA NA 130 -120 NA NA ...
# $ UnderPayout          : int  NA -147 116 -148 NA NA -165 -135 NA NA ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can use `unlist()` or `flatten()` from the `purrr` package.